# How can we deploy a REST service as jar?

Tags: java, rest, jar

I have been asked to create a maven project which handles REST calls and it should not be a web project and not spring project. I would like to deploy the project as a jar in an application server. Is it possible? 
I able to create a rest webservice using spring and resteasy and jersey but they all are created as web project. Online I see most of the examples as web project

Comment: everything is possible. But do you want to reinvent the wheel and do all from scratch if yes! where are your efforts in this question? what have you tried so far?

Comment: please ignore this question. unable to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring Boot is pretty easy and straight forward. You can simply build a Jar of the project and deploy the server on any machine which has java. (NOTE: Spring Boot is an enhancement over Spring as it allows you to focus on the Business Logic while making configuration related stuff minimal)

If you really don't want to use spring boot then JAX-RS is another option as well where the server can be deployed using a JAR file in a Jetty Embedded Server.